Create a rmarkdown file and update parameters programatically
TLDR: I would like to create a rmarkdown file programatically based on a template, while populating the values of their parameters.
I know that rmarkdown::draft() can be used to "Create (and optionally edit) a draft of an R Markdown document based on a template."
I know that rmarkdown documents can have parameters (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html).
I would like to programatically create an rmarkdown document based on a template while populating the values on their parameters, but draft() doesn't seem to allow that. Is this possible?
If not, would it be possible to make changes to the document (such as changing the title or some values?).

I'm not clear on what form your parameters are in and how you want to generate your outputs. Here's a recent blog post about a process that sounds similar, using Posit's quarto, a "next generation" variation of rmarkdown: https://rfortherestofus.com/2024/06/parameterized-reporting-quarto

If you want to use rmarkdown, you could use the same approach as the linked blog post, using rmarkdown::render(INPUT, OUTPUT_FILE, params = PARAMS) and then iterating with a loop or purrr::walk to run the file for each set of parameters.

You should use draft() to create the document, and then use @JonSpring's suggestion to fill in parameter values when you render it.
For example, your template could look like this:
---
title: "`r params$title`"
author: "Duncan Murdoch"
date: "`r params$date`"
output: html_document
params: 
  title: "A default title"
  date: "Today"
  topic: "A default topic"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Introduction

This is a document about `r params$topic`.

When testing, you can use "knit with parameters" in RStudio, and you'll be prompted for entries for title, date and topic.  In production, you can use
rmarkdown::render("docname.Rmd", 
                  params=list(title = "The Title", 
                              date = Sys.Date(), 
                              topic = "Some topic")

